# Programmatically fill grid in wpf: auto rowheight doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls, grid

I'm filling a WPF Grid programmatically with rows. Each row is assigned a user control. This user control contains a Grid itself, with exactly one row and 3 columns. The 3rd column can contain a TextBox, a ComboBox or a variable number of CheckBoxes in a ListBox.

Though I have set the rowheight in the user control and the Grid containing the user control to Auto, the height of the row does not expand. The lower checkboxes just disappear. I've tried different things but no luck yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hi try something like this

```
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

in codebehind

```
DataGrid dg=new DataGrid();
        Style style = new Style(typeof(DataGridRow));
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridRow.HeightProperty,new GridLength(20, GridUnitType.Auto)));
        dg.RowStyle=style;
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: i have updated the answer to apply style using code. and 20 in height is minheight and you can set it according to your requirement.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work as Auto isn't a valid value for the Height property.  It looks like it only accepts doubles. :(

Comment: I down-voted the answer because the question asked for programmatic solution, and the supplied solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

For set "Auto" Width or Height from XAML you can use double.Nan instead "Value="Auto"".

```
<DataGrid>
   <DataGrid.RowStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
         <Setter Property="Height" Value="{x:Static sys:Double.NaN}"/>
      </Style>
   </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Don't forget to add

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

for using "sys" in head of your XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate row height in code behind yourself...

```
myGrid.RowHeight = myGrid.RenderSize.Height / myGrid.ItemsSource.Cast<MyRowDef>().Count();
```